# What could prevent SQL Server from treating a query filter optimally

Tags: sql-server

What could prevent SQL Server from treating a query filter optimally, meaning, from using an index efficiently to support the filter? What other query elements could also be affected in a similar manner and what can you do to get optimal treatment?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. Some examples that preclude efficient index use include data type conversions and applying a function to a column in `WHERE`  clause (non-sargable expression). Consider adding a specific example that includes DDL and query with a filter where the index is not used optimally.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question - it would be good to have more details about your specific situation if you want help with something.

Therefore the answers here are only pointers to potential problems - you will need to do research into how to fix them in your own specific circumstances

**SQL-Server issues**

- Parameter sniffing and cached execution plans - occurs in stored procedures, where the first time you run it saves an execution plan that isn't great for the same procedure with other parameters.
- Complex queries causing poor cardinality estimation - this doesn't often affect choice of indexes imo, but it can (especially if you have multiple indexes on the same table)

**Human issues**

In these, SQL Server doesn't use an index - but is correct in (not) doing so.

- Index fields are in the wrong order e.g., you have training records with an indexed on `Student_ID` then `Unit_ID`. You try to `select * from trgrecords WHERE Unit_ID = 100`. The index doesn't help you much here - it would still need to read all rows of the index to determine which rows match. This also compounds with the problem below.
- Inappropriate belief that an index-seek/key-lookup pair is faster. When you're filtering by an index (that isn't a covering index) and it will return a decent proportion of rows, SQL Server will often read the whole table rather than looking up all the relevant rows one-by-one. And it's usually right. But you may think it's not right. (Also note - usually the problem is the other way - SQL Server uses an index-seek/key-lookup strategy when a full scan would be better).
- `SELECT *` (e.g., in sub-queries). Because this is telling SQL Server to get all fields, it will always go to the clustered index at some point (even if you're only needing a few columns/fields) unless you have an index across all fields (not common!). This forces the issue above about index-seek/key-lookups.
- Non-SARGable WHERE clauses etc - e.g., `SELECT Name FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE 'Simon%'` is SARGable, while `SELECT Name FROM Person WHERE LEFT(Name, 5) = 'Simon'` is not SARGable. By definition, non-SARGable queries require a full scan of the appropriate data.

I suggest watching these by Brent Ozar - I learned a lot from them.

- [How to think like an SQL Server engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fERXOywBhlA)
- [Identifying and fixing Parameter sniffing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd7xqLT_-2k)